# Merging two Excel sheets by matching on two columns

Tags: performance, vba, excel

I have 2 sheets with the exact format, 5 columns (Category1, Category2, Category3, Month, Amount) - "Temp" and "Source".

My goal is to copy the data from "Source" to a new sheet("Combined"), append the data from "Temp" but replace the rows that are matching on column C and D with the new rows from "Temp".

For now I have the following code that does the job:

```
Option Explicit

Sub Verify()
Dim c As Range
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
last3 = Sheets("Temp").Cells(Application.Rows.count, "A").End(xlUp).row
last4 = Sheets("Source").Cells(Application.Rows.count, "A").End(xlUp).row
last5 = Sheets("Combined").Cells(Application.Rows.count, "A").End(xlUp).row

' Clear Contents
Sheets("Combined").Range("A1:E" & last5).ClearContents

    Sheets("Temp").Range("G2").Formula = "=C2&D2"
    Sheets("Temp").Range("G2").Copy Destination:=Sheets("Temp").Range("G3:G" & last3)

    Sheets("Source").Range("G2").Formula = "=C2&D2"
    Sheets("Source").Range("G2").Copy Destination:=Sheets("Source").Range("G3:G" & last4)

    Sheets("Source").Range("H2").Formula = "=MATCH(G2,Temp!$G$2:$G$" & last3 & ",0)"
    Sheets("Source").Range("H2").Copy Destination:=Sheets("Source").Range("H3:H" & last4)

' Copy & Format Headers
Sheets("Temp").Range("A1:E1").Copy Destination:=Sheets("Combined").Range("A1")

' Copy All Data from Temp
Sheets("Temp").Range("A2:E" & last3).Copy Destination:=Sheets("Combined").Range("A2")

' Copy Selected Data from Source
    For Each c In Sheets("Source").Range("H2:H" & last4)
        If IsError(c) Then
          last5 = Sheets("Combined").Cells(Application.Rows.count, "A").End(xlUp).row
          Sheets("Source").Range("A" & c.row & ":E" & c.row).Copy Destination:=Sheets("Combined").Range("A" & last5 + 1)
        End If
    Next c

' Clean temp Columns
Sheets("Temp").Columns("G:G").Delete
Sheets("Source").Columns("G:H").Delete
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

My problem with it is that is too slow(~15.000 rows). It freezes my excel with a white screen for a few minutes but in the end it works. I have tried using DoEvents but it is still really slow.

I am sure there a better way to achieve what I am looking for. Can someone please help me rewrite the VBA to speed it up? I would be grateful if I could at least get it not to freeze or increase the performance somehow.

Answer (score 3):

If no one offered a suggestion, I have found a way to handle this. This makes it blazing fast:

```
Sub Verify()
Dim c As Range, last3 As Long, last4 As Long, last5 As Long
Dim wt As Worksheet, ws As Worksheet, wc As Worksheet
Set wt = Sheets("Temp"): Set ws = Sheets("Source"): Set wc = Sheets("Combined")
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

last3 = wt.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
last4 = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
last5 = wc.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

wc.Cells.ClearContents ' Clear Contents
wt.Range("G2").Resize(last3 - 1, 1).Formula = "=C2&D2"
ws.Range("G2").Resize(last4 - 1, 1).Formula = "=C2&D2"
ws.Range("H2").Resize(last4 - 1, 1).Formula = "=MATCH(G2,Temp!$G$2:$G$" & last3 & ",0)"

' Copy & Format Headers
wt.Range("A1:E1").Copy wc.Range("A1")

' Copy All Data from Temp
wt.Range("A2:E" & last3).Copy wc.Range("A2")

' Copy Selected Data from Source
    For Each c In ws.Range("H2:H" & last4)
        If IsError(c) Then
          last5 = wc.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    wc.Range("A" & last5 + 1).Resize(1, 5).Value = ws.Range("A" & c.Row).Resize(1, 5).Value
    End If
    Next c
' Clean temp Columns
Application.DisplayAlerts = False: wt.Columns("G").Delete: ws.Columns("G:H").Delete
Application.DisplayAlerts = True: Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```